# Saving the objective function values while using Solver, EXCEL

Tags: optimization, vba, excel, solver

I have an optimization problem set up in Excel. When I optimize (using the gui), I get the final (optimum) value of the objective function. I can see that excel calculates the objective function values for a lot of points and settles on the optimum one. Is there a way to save all the objective function values to some range in the excel sheet. It would be great if I can do it using the solver GUI. If not, a VBA based solution would do too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do, but is manually tedious. When in Excel/Solver, select *Options* in the *Solver Parameters Dialog.* (**Data->Solver->Options** in Excel) Select the **Show Iterations Results** check box. When you do this, Excel's Solver will pause after each iteration, and update the cells with the current variable values.

Now, when you run the model by clicking "**Solve**," Excel will pause at each intermediate iteration. Solver considers each intermediate step to be a "**Scenario**." You can save each one by giving it a name in the **Scenario dialog box** that pops up after each iteration. (In the text box, enter something logical, like i1,i2, i3...)

Once the Solver is done, you can access the 'Scenario Manager" **Excel->Options->Scenarios**.
You will see all the scenarios that you saved listed there. To get them all into a named range like you desire, press the "**Summary**" button, and in the dialog box choose "**Scenario Pivot Table Report**." This will display all the intermediate Objective function values in a nice *Pivot Table* for you to analyze.

A couple of limitations to keep in mind:
1. Enabling the "**Show Iteration Results**" option severely slows down the solution
2. If your LP is even mid-sized, you will have a huge number of iterations. Manually recording the scenarios will not be realistically feasible. However, you can "sample" a few iterations by pressing the **ESC** button, storing the Scenario and continuing.